# How to make 301 redirect in Netlify work?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, netlify

1. I can't get the 301 redirect to work in Netlify at all (I've seen other answers, but it doesn't work).
2. I've made the _redirects file and placed it in the root of my github ripo.

   `https://some-domain.netlify.com/* https://www.mydomain.tk/:splat 301!`

I expect it that when someone types this: https://some-domain.netlify.com/ he will be redirected to here: https://www.mydomain.tk  , but that doesn't happen.

2. I'm trying to redirect https://some-domain.netlify.com/ to https://www.mydomain.tk/portofolio/
   this didn't work either

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that the `_redirects` file does not go to the root of your repository unless the root of your repository is your deploy path.

The `_redirects` file must be placed into the root of your deploy path.

#### example

In the case below, the deploy directory after the build command is `public` in the repository.

```
root
  ├ public
  | ├ _redirects
  | └ index.html
  ├ src
  └ lib
```

***Note:*** Remember that you can also put redirects in your `netlify.toml` file. The `netlify.toml` file does go in the root of the repository.

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  publish = "public"

[[redirects]]
  from = "https://some-domain.netlify.com/*"
  to = "https://www.mydomain.tk/:splat"
  status = 301
  force = true
```

There is a [playground to build](https://play.netlify.com/redirects) them from the `_redirects` format to `netlify.toml` format

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. The editing of the netlify.toml worked perfectly. I've tried putting the _redirects file directly in the "public" folder and then update github, but that didn't work, maybe because the public folder is not sent to github but created when netlify runs the build. So, you have to do the editing of the netlify.toml file as in your example.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be put in the deploy folder after the build or have a build process like a static folder that gets copied during the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a domain alias, as discussed here:

https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/multiple-domains/

and avoid the `_redirects` file method -- I think this only works of your using netlify for DNS.